# OpenGL shader error

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm writing an openGL program using the wxWidgets library, I have it mostly working, but I am getting shader compilation errors due to bad characters being inserted (I think), only I can't find where the characters are or what is causing them. The error is :

```
error 0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"
```

I'm not sure why though, since I can't see any errors when I cout the string. Here is what is being fed to glshadersource() :

```
#version 430 core

layout(location =0) in vec3 vpos;

out vec3 fragmentColor;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(void)

{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vpos,1);
};
```

Here are the shader compiler functions I use:

```
void GL_set::compileAndLink()
{

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength = 0;

    // Create vertex shader, attach source code, compile
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const GLchar* adapter[1];
    adapter[0] = readShaderCode("Vshader.glsl").c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, adapter, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Check vertex shader for errors
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0)
    {
        char vertexError[1000];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, InfoLogLength, NULL, &vertexError[0]);
        std::cout << &vertexError[0];
    }

    // Create fragment shader, attach source code, compile
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    adapter[0] = readShaderCode("Fshader.glsl").c_str();
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, adapter, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Check fragment shader for errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0)
    {
        char fragmentError[1000];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, InfoLogLength, NULL, 
        &fragmentError[0]);
        std::cout << &fragmentError[0];
    }

    // Create program and attach shaders
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    //check program for errors
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0)
    {
        char programError[1000];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, InfoLogLength, NULL, &programError[0]);
        std::cout << &programError[0];
    }

}



std::string GL_set::readShaderCode(const char* fileName)
{
    printf("passing %s to readShaderCode() \n", fileName);
    std::ifstream input(fileName);
    if(!input.good())
    {
        std::cout << "failed to load file " << fileName;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string code = std::string(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
    );

    // output the code to cout for error checking
    std::cout << "Read shader input: \n" << code << "\n" << std::endl;


    return code;
}
```

Here is the full console output:

```
normal display attribs are supported
calling gl_init()
gl_set construtor called
setting buffers
passing Vshader.glsl to readShaderCode()
Read shader input:
#version 430 core

layout(location =0) in vec3 vpos;

out vec3 fragmentColor;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(void)
{
    //output position of the vertex in clip space MVP*position
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vpos,1);
};



0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"
passing Fshader.glsl to readShaderCode()
Read shader input:
#version 430 core

in vec3 fragmentColor;

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    color = fragmentColor;
};



0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"
Vertex info
-----------
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "
<undefined>"
(0) : error C2003: incompatible options for link

Fragment info
-------------
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"
(0) : error C2003: incompatible options for link
Loading OBJ file mod.obj...
```

Here is the rest of the class:

```
#include "GL_set.h"

GL_set::GL_set()
{

    std::cout << "gl_set construtor called" << std::endl;

    GL_set::setBuffers();

}


void GL_set::setBuffers()
{

    std::cout << "setting buffers" << std::endl;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    //create shaders and attach them to the program object
    GL_set::compileAndLink();

    loadOBJ("mod.obj", vdata); // use OBJ loader

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vdata.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3), &vdata[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //vertex buffer
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,          //index
        3,          //size
        GL_FLOAT,   //type
        GL_FALSE,   //normalized?
        0,          //stride
        0           //array buffer offset
    );

}

void GL_set::draw()
{

    glBindVertexArray(vao);


    GLuint matrixID = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");


    ////////////////////////////matrix operations/////////////////////////////////////////

    //projection matrix 45 degree FoV, 4:3 ratio, display range 0.1 - 100
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f/3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    //camera matrix
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
                 glm::vec3(8, 8,  8), //camera posiiton
                 glm::vec3(0, 1,  0), //camera looks at this point
                 glm::vec3(0, 1,  0)  //head up position
                 );

    //model matrix identity matrix
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    //rotate
    model = glm::rotate(model, 1.0f, glm::vec3(1,1,1));

    //model-view-projection
    glm::mat4 MVP = projection * view * model;



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);


    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vdata.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3));


}
```

I think the wxWidgets related code I have is okay, the window interface loads with a blank white screen, presumably caused by the shader errors. I can post more if needed, thanks.

Comment: How do expect the Fragment Shader gets `fragmentColor`from? Uncomment the "out" command in the Vertex Shader, set some value for it  and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::string` returned by `readShaderCode` only lives for the duration of the `.c_str()` call. After that, the `std::string` implementation is allowed to free the memory, leaving your `adapter[0]` point to memory that has just been freed (a use-after-free).

You should assign the result of `readShaderCode` to a local `std::string` variable such that the memory is only freed at the end of the function. You can then safely store the result of `.c_str()` into `adapter`, knowing that the memory has not been freed yet.